# User.Identity.Name becoming null but I cant understand why

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

Basically I keep getting thrown out from my asp.net mvc application because the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false, this only happens because of the code below related to task comments (marked ** below) - I cannot figure out why it is happening, any help is appreciated.

Code below inside a custom attribute on my base controller that authenticates users, if not authenticated I throw an exception like so:

```
if (!httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
   throw new NoAccessException("unauthorized user"); // invalid users are thrown out...
```

Code that is causing the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated + User.Identity.Name to become null is:

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult TaskDetail(int houseid, int taskid)
    {

        //NOTE: _repo is a simple ISession over Linq to Sql
        //GetCurrentUser() is a extention method which gets the current logged on user
        //i.e. User.Identity.Name so I can get the users credentials

        var loggedonuser = _repo.GetCurrentUser();

        var _house= _repo.Single<House>(x => x.HouseID== houseid&& x.ClientID== loggedonuser.CompanyID);

        if (_house== null)
            throw new NoAccessException();

        var summary = _instruction.ToSummaryDTO();

        var companies = _repo.All<Company>();
        //var users = _repo.All<User>();

        var task = _repo.Single<Task>
            (x => x.HouseID== _house.HouseID && x.CompanyID == loggedonuser.CompanyID);

        var dto = new TaskDTO
        {
            TaskID = task.TaskID,
            Title = task.Title,
            Description = task.Description,
            DateCreated = task.DateCreated,
            IsClosed = task.IsClosed,
            CompanyID = companies.Where(y => task.CompanyID == y.CompanyID).SingleOrDefault().Identifier
        };

        **dto.AllComments** = _repo.All<TaskComment>()
            .Where(x => x.TaskID == task.TaskID)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Timestamp)
            .Select(x => new TaskCommentDTO
            {
                Comment = x.Comment,
                Timestamp = x.Timestamp,
                CompanyID = companies.Where(y => x.CompanyID == y.CompanyID).SingleOrDefault().Identifier
            });


        return View(new TaskViewModel
        {
            Summary = summary,
            TaskDetail = dto,
        });
    }
```

**NOTE:** If I omit the dto.AllComments (IQueryable) then everything works fine, I never get thrown out my system or more importantly User.Identitiy remains correct.... I have tried to convert to list - which is what I ideally want however that does not work either, maybe there is something wrong with my linq method...

My DTO:

```
public class TaskDTO
{
    public int TaskID { get; set; }
    public bool IsClosed { get; set; }
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<TaskCommentDTO> AllComments { get; set; }
}


public class TaskCommentDTO
{
    public string CompanyID { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

**EDIT: where exception is being thrown**

I have traced the exception now, I overrided the code below in my base controller which helped me discover the bug:

```
    protected override void Execute(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Execute(requestContext);
    }
```

After the page finished loading, this code was ran once again, when I checked out the request context In the Values for RouteData I found "Error" and "FileNotFound", at this point the user gets nulled out too, now I need to find out which file is not found... :(

Comment: Did you try debugging to see exactly which line throws the exception? Try stepping through and watch the variables to see what happens.

Comment: Yes- As soon as my filter runs, the NoAccessException is thrown as shown above, before that I cannot trace because I am not sure what code if any is run before my filter... besides as I mentioned if I remove the code related to comments everything works...

Comment: Does the linq query look ok to you?

Comment: Posted below to try and help track where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code:

```
var task = _repo.Single<Task>
            (x => x.HouseID == _house.HouseID && x.CompanyID == loggedonuser.CompanyID);

    var dto = new TaskDTO
    {
        TaskID = task.TaskID,
        Title = task.Title,
        Description = task.Description,
        DateCreated = task.DateCreated,
        IsClosed = task.IsClosed,
        CompanyID = companies.Where(y => task.CompanyID == y.CompanyID).SingleOrDefault().Identifier
    };
```

This line:

```
CompanyID = companies.Where(y => task.CompanyID == y.CompanyID).SingleOrDefault().Identifier
```

calls the property `Identifier` on a `SingleOrDefault()` result which could be `null`. Have you checked that this is ok. Is it on this line that the exception is thrown?

Note you can use `IEnumerable` instead of `IQueryable`; probably won't make any difference but if that's the crashing part you can try it for nothing.

Comment: I removed the call to companies and that did nothing... I find it really weird that on the 1st request to this url everything works, any other requests fail... could there be an issue with the linq to sql mappings? or something else?

Comment: Can you confirm by adding a breakpoint at the start of the function, which line throws the exception. Can you use F11 to step into that line's function calls?

Comment: @Chris- see updated question, managed to find where the problem is occurring (I think)...

Comment: Keep debugging. Sounds like you're on your way to tracking it down.

Comment: Found it... I copied and pasted a css image link from somewhere, maybe i assumed it to be a jquery ui image and that is what was throwing the exception, man I need to be kicked! I appreciate your help anyway, thank you.

Comment: The worst thing is, I have just checked my logs more carefully, and the error is crystal clear! :(

Comment: Glad you found it. Gave you a +1 for expanding your question to help find the answer.